# Why does the derivation for the Michelson & Morley time difference assume Earth moves in only one direction relative to the Aether?

Tags: special-relativity, galilean-relativity, aether

In the Michelson and Morley experiment, we predict with Galilean relativity and the assumption of the existence of a luminiferous aether that there should be a time difference between the two beams of light reaching the detector of an interferometer with arms of equal length. This time difference is given by:

$$ \Delta t = \frac{2L}{c} (\gamma^2 - \gamma) $$

where $\gamma$ is the Lorentz constant, $c$ is the speed of light from the IRF of the aether, and $L$ is the length of the length of two arms of the interferometer.

This was derived under the assumption that the IRF of the experiment ("Earth") moves through the Aether at a velocity $V$ in a single direction as shown in the diagram below.

[image]

The derivation was similar to the derivation on Wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment#Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment_(1887)) which also uses this assumption. My question is, why is this assumption is allowed when surely the Earth could be moving with a velocity in the y-direction as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the device anywhere on the earth, orient it any way that you want, and conduct the experiment at any time of the year.  In *some* orientation of the device, the veclocity of  the aether will be in the $x$ direction, and in this direction, you would expect the time of flight difference between the legs to be maximized.

Comment: but could there not also be a velocity in the y-direction at this orientation which would affect the time difference? shouldn't this be included in the equation?

Comment: @physBa : the point is, if, in the diagram above, you have a velocity in the y direction, you simply rotate the apparatus until the new y component of the velocity is zero.

Comment: Namely, the ether has *some* net velocity relative to the apparatus, and you're free to orient the apparatus however you wish.  Pick the orientation that gives you the maximum signal.

Comment: Oh yeah! There is always going to be a net velocity and the apparatus can be rotated so that the net velocity coincides with the x-axis. Ty